Does the Catholic Church recognize Protestant baptism?
Does the Catholic Church recognize Protestant baptism?
What if one wants to convert to Catholicism, but can't get baptized, or they originally were part of a protestant church and were baptized and wish to convert. How exactly would that work?

The answer is a clear yes (see https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/96708/since-when-did-the-catholic-church-accept-protestant-baptism-and-what-was-the-o), but the part of your question about conversions isn't answered there so I haven't marked this as a duplicate yet.

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Does the Catholic Church recognize Protestant baptism?
That will depend on the particular Protestant denomination on was baptized in. The Catholic Church recognizes many baptisms of Protestant Christians, but not all!
Valid versus invalid baptisms may be found here.
Protestant denominations are very numerous. Here follows a small sample:

Protestants can be differentiated according to how they have been influenced by important movements since the Reformation, today regarded as branches. Some of these movements have a common lineage, sometimes directly spawning individual denominations. Due to the earlier stated multitude of denominations, this section discusses only the largest denominational families, or branches, widely considered to be a part of Protestantism. These are, in alphabetical order: Adventist, Anglican, Baptist, Calvinist (Reformed), Hussite, Lutheran, Methodist, Pentecostal, Plymouth Brethren and Quaker. A small but historically significant Anabaptist branch is also discussed. - Protestantism

Those Protestants desiring to become Catholic, if already validly baptized would simply have to make a ”profession of faith” in the presence of a Catholic minister after a studying the teachings of the Catholic Church. One can only be validly baptized once. Those not yet baptized or invalidly baptized would need to be baptized into the Catholic Church, again after a serious examination and reflection of the teachings of the Catholic Church.

If I am correct, it has nothing to do with the denominations themselves, but rather the form of their baptisms.
